# how to convert a list of maps in neo4j into list of ids?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a scenario where i have a list of map. 
`[ {'User ID': <int>,'user name': <chars>},{'User ID': <int>,'user name': <chars>}.... and so on]`

So i wanted to understand as how to extract only the user id from this list and create a list of user ids in neo4j. 
I have tried following:

```
filter(users in usersList where userList.id is not null) as usersIds
```

Answer (score 1):

There's something called [list comprehension](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/syntax/lists/#cypher-list-comprehension) which combines the functionality of both `filter()` and `extract()`:

```
...
WITH [user in usersList WHERE user.id IS NOT NULL | user.id] as ids
...
```